# BC30456 'Computer' is not a member of 'NAME.My'

Tags: vb.net

I deployed this code in order to delete a file via the recycle bin. However I get the following error  : BC30456    'Computer' is not a member of 'NAME.My'!

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.DeleteFile("C:\essai.librairie",
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.UIOption.AllDialogs,
Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.RecycleOption.SendToRecycleBin)
```

The data saved in the files is in UTF-8 BOM format. Target framework : .NET Core 3.1 What do you think ?

Claude

Comment: I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that the `My` namespace was implemented in .NET Core 3.1 or earlier. That's why VB projects targeting .NET Core were limited to Console apps. I think you'll need to target .NET Framework or .NET 5.0, or use a different option to delete.

Comment: Indeed, I made a mistake when I created a project! I have therefore recreated a Windows Forms application with Framework 5.0 and it now works. Thank you jmcilhinney :)